# Android Using only ViewPager from Support Library

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The new edition of my app has a minimum SDK of 14, so I thought that I could get rid of the support.v4 library that I've been using for the older version. However, it now looks like I might have to use ViewPager and thus am back to including the library.

So can I just use the ViewPager-related classes from the library and not have to use the other classes that are now native in V14, such as Fragment (and also not have to change Activity to FragmentActivity)?

I would assume that I can do this (only use ViewPager from the library) but wanted to check to make sure.

Comment: It just depends where you import declaration it. Just remember to import your ViewPager for V4 , and everything else import from newer libs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to use v13 support libraries for some things.  If what you want to use exists in both v4 and v13, use v13. v13 works with Fragments native to the higher APIs, while v4 only works with v4 fragments.

Comment: Actually, looking at the sample project that came with the V13 library, it looks like I can use ViewPager from V4, FragmentPagerAdapter from V13, and the native classes for Fragment and all the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a project that has only ViewPager and it's closest dependencies - without Fragments and without actionbar, which are supported natively as of api level 14.

https://github.com/kilaka/ViewPager-Independent

Enjoy :)